# input_event structure description (from linux/input.h)

Tags: c++, c, linux, input, structure

Can someone please tell me what are the properties of the datatypes used by the input_event structure?

It is defined as follows in the input.h file:

```
struct input_event {
struct timeval time;
__u16 type;
__u16 code;
__s32 value;
};
```

but there are no other descriptions! Even googling gave me nothing interesting.

The only thing I know is that `time` gives seconds or miliseconds from epoch and `value` gives code of pressed button. But even value of `value` property isn't really clear for me. In my program every keystroke generates six events. Following events are response for pressing ENTER key:

```
type=4,code=4,value=458792
type=1,code=28,value=1
type=0,code=0,value=0
type=4,code=4,value=458792
type=1,code=28,value=0
type=0,code=0,value=0
```

and those are for `a` letter:

```
type=4,code=4,value=458756
type=1,code=30,value=1
type=0,code=0,value=0
atype=4,code=4,value=458756
type=1,code=30,value=0
type=0,code=0,value=0
```

I would like to decode value to the real letter, but I don't understand the meaning of the properties.

Please help!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `struct input_event` is, among others, defined in [include/linux/input.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input.h).

---

From *5. Event interface* in Linux kernel [Documentation/input/input.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) (and modified to provide the correct header file names):

- `time` is the timestamp, it returns the time at which the event happened.
- `type` is for example `EV_REL` for relative moment, `EV_KEY` for a keypress or
  release. More types are defined in [include/linux/input-event-codes.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h).
- `code` is event code, for example `REL_X` or `KEY_BACKSPACE`, again a complete
  list is in [include/linux/input-event-codes.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h).
- `value` is the value the event carries. Either a relative change for
  `EV_REL`, absolute new value for `EV_ABS` (joysticks ...), or `0` for `EV_KEY` for
  release, `1` for keypress and `2` for autorepeat.

For guides and example code, do a web search for [`"linux kernel" "input subsystem"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="linux+kernel"+"input+subsystem").