# Read barcodes from input-event (linux, c)

Tags: c, linux, device, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a small program that read barcodes from /dev/input/event4.
This is the code:

```
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct input_event ev;
        int fd, rd;

        //Open Device
        if ((fd = open ("/dev/input/event4", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) == -1){
                printf ("not a vaild device.\n");
                return -1;
        }

        while (1){

                memset((void*)&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));

                rd = read (fd, (void*)&ev, sizeof(ev));

                if (rd <= 0){
                        printf ("rd: %d\n", rd);
                        sleep(1);
                }

                if(rd>0 && ev.value==0 && ev.type==1){
                        printf("type: %d, code: %d, value: %d, rd: %d\n", ev.type, ev.code, ev.value, rd);
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I have now created some barcodes with an online-generator (http://www.barcode-generator.de/V2/de/index.jsp). The barcodes are:
123456789 and 1234567890

The output of my programm when scanning the barcodes is:

```
type: 1, code: 2, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 3, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 4, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 5, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 6, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 7, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 8, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 9, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 10, value: 0, rd: 16
type: 1, code: 28, value: 0, rd: 16
```

for the 123456789

and

```
type: 1, code: 28, value: 0, rd: 16
```

for the 1234567890

So, the 10-digit-barcodes is not recognised correctly.

The code: 28 means this is an RETURN/ENTER, this is the internal terminator for a barcode, so this comes directly from the scanner.

Does anyone can tell my why ? Maybe there is something wrong with the code ?

Goodbye, Andre

Comment: I tried your code by replacing file with a text file opening it is printing everything as expected. I don't think any wrong with the code

Comment: You have to be careful with that check for failed read. You should really handle the case when `read` returns separately, and also check what `errno` is when `read` returns `-1` (as you don't know if it's an error or no data available).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should only consider the event when the `read()` returns `== sizeof ev`, because we're reading from an input device here. If it returns zero, it means no more events are forthcoming (maybe device detached?). If it returns `-1`, check `errno`. If `read()` returns any other value, the kernel driver has gone bonkers and you could consider it a fatal error.

`errno == EINTR` is normal (occurs when a signal is delivered), it is not an error per se. It shouldn't happen here, but ignoring it (treating it as just a hiccup, not an error) is quite safe.

`errno == EAGAIN` occurs when you used `O_NONBLOCK` in the `open()` flags, and there is no new event available yet.

There is absolutely no reason to use `O_NONBLOCK` here. All it does is causes your code to waste CPU cycles, returning tens of thousands of times per second from the `read()` call just to return `-1` with `errno == EAGAIN`. Just drop it, so that the `read()` will simply wait until a new event arrives, and returns it.

See my answer to the [input_event structure description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695758/1475978) question.

In summary, for `ev_type == 1 == EV_KEY`:

- `ev_value == 0`: key released (key up)
- `ev_value == 1`: key pressed (key down)
- `ev_value == 2`: autorepeat (key automatically repeated)
- `ev_code == 1 == KEY_ESC`
- `ev_code == 2 == KEY_1`
- `ev_code == 3 == KEY_2`
- `ev_code == 10 == KEY_9`
- `ev_code == 11 == KEY_0`
- `ev_code == 28 == KEY_ENTER`

The keypresses the device provided are actually <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(Note that you only showed the key release events; you should actually see two, one with `ev_value == 1`, followed by one with `ev_value == 0`, for each `ev_code`.)

The one Chinese one I've tried was very nice, although dirt cheap. It had a manual with a few barcodes, including some to switch between barcode formats (and number of digits). I vaguely remember using two barcodes to switch to another mode, and to use the minimum volume for the beeps. It seemed to retain the settings even after being detached.

---

Here is an example of what kind of implementation I'd use to read barcodes. I'd obviously split the barcode reading part to a separate file.

The below code is dedicated to public domain (licensed under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)), so feel free to use it in any way you wish. There is no guarantees of any kind, so don't blame me for any breakage. (Any bug fixes are welcome; if reported, I will check and include in the below code. I recommend adding a comment below; I do read all comments to my answers every couple of days or so.)

The header file `barcode.h`:

```
#ifndef   BARCODE_H
#define   BARCODE_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* This flags turns nonzero if any signal
 * installed with install_done is caught.
*/
extern volatile sig_atomic_t done;

/* Install signals that set 'done'.
*/
int install_done(const int signum);

/* Barcode device description.
 * Do not meddle with the internals;
 * this is here only to allow you
 * to allocate one statically.
*/
typedef struct {
    int             fd;
    volatile int    timeout;
    timer_t         timer;
} barcode_dev;

/* Close a barcode device.
 * Returns 0 if success, nonzero errno error code otherwise.
*/
int barcode_close(barcode_dev *const dev);

/* Open a barcode device.
 * Returns 0 if success, nonzero errno error code otherwise.
*/
int barcode_open(barcode_dev *const dev, const char *const device_path);

/* Read a barcode, but do not spend more than maximum_ms.
 * Returns the length of the barcode read.
 * (although at most length-1 characters are saved at the buffer,
 *  the total length of the barcode is returned.)
 * errno is always set; 0 if success, error code otherwise.
 * If the reading timed out, errno will be set to ETIMEDOUT.
*/
size_t barcode_read(barcode_dev *const dev,
                    char *const buffer, const size_t length,
                    const unsigned long maximum_ms);

#endif /* BARCODE_H */
```

The implementation in the following `barcode.c` file currently accepts only digits (0 through 1), but it should be trivial to add any other necessary keys (like `KEY_A` through `KEY_Z`). The current one ignores shift, control, et cetera, as they are not provided by any scanners as far as I know. It uses `SIGRTMAX-0` realtime signal and a custom timer per barcode device to read barcodes, so you'll need to link it against `librt` (`-lrt`):

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Link against the rt library; -lrt. */

#define UNUSED          __attribute__((unused))
#define TIMEOUT_SIGNAL  (SIGRTMAX-0)

/*
 * done - flag used to exit program at SIGINT, SIGTERM etc.
*/

volatile sig_atomic_t done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum UNUSED)
{
    done = 1;
}

int install_done(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Barcode input event device, and associated timeout timer.
*/

typedef struct {
    int             fd;
    volatile int    timeout;
    timer_t         timer;
} barcode_dev;

static void handle_timeout(int signum UNUSED, siginfo_t *info, void *context UNUSED)
{
    if (info && info->si_code == SI_TIMER && info->si_value.sival_ptr)
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
        __atomic_add_fetch((int *)info->si_value.sival_ptr, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
#else
        __sync_add_and_fetch((int *)info->si_value.sival_ptr, 1);
#endif
}

static int install_timeouts(void)
{
    static int installed = 0;

    if (!installed) {
        struct sigaction act;
        sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
        act.sa_sigaction = handle_timeout;
        act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        if (sigaction(TIMEOUT_SIGNAL, &act, NULL) == -1)
            return errno;
        installed = 1;        
    }

    return 0;
}

int barcode_close(barcode_dev *const dev)
{
    int retval = 0;

    if (!dev)
        return 0;

    if (dev->fd != -1)
        if (close(dev->fd) == -1)
            retval = errno;

    dev->fd = -1;

    if (dev->timer)
        if (timer_delete(dev->timer) == -1)
            if (!retval)
                retval = errno;

    dev->timer = (timer_t)0;

    /* Handle all pending TIMEOUT_SIGNALs */
    while (1) {
        struct timespec t;
        siginfo_t info;
        sigset_t s;

        t.tv_sec = (time_t)0;
        t.tv_nsec = 0L;
        sigemptyset(&s);

        if (sigtimedwait(&s, &info, &t) != TIMEOUT_SIGNAL)
            break;

        if (info.si_code != SI_TIMER || !info.si_value.sival_ptr)
            continue;

#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
        __atomic_add_fetch((int *)info.si_value.sival_ptr, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
#else
        __sync_add_and_fetch((int *)info.si_value.sival_ptr, 1);
#endif
    }

    return errno = retval;
}

int barcode_open(barcode_dev *const dev, const char *const device_path)
{
    struct sigevent event;
    int fd;

    if (!dev)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    dev->fd = -1;
    dev->timeout = -1;
    dev->timer = (timer_t)0;

    if (!device_path || !*device_path)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    if (install_timeouts())
        return errno;

    do {
        fd = open(device_path, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    errno = 0;
    if (ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1)) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        close(fd);
        return errno = (saved_errno) ? errno : EACCES;
    }

    dev->fd = fd;

    memset(&event, 0, sizeof event);
    event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    event.sigev_signo = TIMEOUT_SIGNAL;
    event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *)&(dev->timeout);
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &event, &dev->timer) == -1) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        close(fd);
        return errno = (saved_errno) ? errno : EMFILE;
    }

    return errno = 0;
}

size_t barcode_read(barcode_dev *const dev,
                    char *const buffer, const size_t length,
                    const unsigned long maximum_ms)
{
    struct itimerspec it;
    size_t len = 0;
    int status = ETIMEDOUT;

    if (!dev || !buffer || length < 2 || maximum_ms < 1UL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (size_t)0;
    }

    /* Initial timeout. */
    it.it_value.tv_sec = maximum_ms / 1000UL;
    it.it_value.tv_nsec = (maximum_ms % 1000UL) * 1000000L;

    /* After elapsing, fire every 10 ms. */
    it.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it.it_interval.tv_nsec = 10000000L;

    if (timer_settime(dev->timer, 0, &it, NULL) == -1)
        return (size_t)0;

    /* Because of the repeated elapsing, it is safe to
     * clear the timeout flag here. */
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR >= 7)
    __atomic_store_n((int *)&(dev->timeout), 0, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
#else
    __sync_fetch_and_and((int *)&(dev->timeout), 0);
#endif

    while (!dev->timeout) {
        struct input_event ev;
        ssize_t n;
        int digit;

        n = read(dev->fd, &ev, sizeof ev);
        if (n == (ssize_t)-1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            status = errno;
            break;

        } else
        if (n == sizeof ev) {

            /* We consider only key presses and autorepeats. */
            if (ev.type != EV_KEY || (ev.value != 1 && ev.value != 2))
                continue;

            switch (ev.code) {
            case KEY_0: digit = '0'; break;
            case KEY_1: digit = '1'; break;
            case KEY_2: digit = '2'; break;
            case KEY_3: digit = '3'; break;
            case KEY_4: digit = '4'; break;
            case KEY_5: digit = '5'; break;
            case KEY_6: digit = '6'; break;
            case KEY_7: digit = '7'; break;
            case KEY_8: digit = '8'; break;
            case KEY_9: digit = '9'; break;
            default:    digit = '\0';
            }

            /* Non-digit key ends the code, except at beginning of code. */
            if (digit == '\0') {
                if (!len)
                    continue;
                status = 0;
                break;
            }

            if (len < length)
                buffer[len] = digit;
            len++;

            continue;

        } else
        if (n == (ssize_t)0) {
            status = ENOENT;
            break;                

        } else {
            status = EIO;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Add terminator character to buffer. */
    if (len + 1 < length)
        buffer[len + 1] = '\0';
    else
        buffer[length - 1] = '\0';

    /* Cancel timeout. */
    it.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    it.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    it.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0L;
    (void)timer_settime(dev->timer, 0, &it, NULL);

    errno = status;
    return len;
}
```

Here is an example program, `example.c`. You supply the input event device (I suggest using a symlink in `/dev/input/by-id/` or `/dev/input/by-path/` if your `udev` provides those, as event device indexes may not be stable across kernel versions and hardware boots), and the maximum duration you're willing to wait for/until next barcode.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "barcode.h"

#define BARCODE_MAXLEN  1023

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    barcode_dev    dev;
    unsigned long  ms;
    int            status, exitcode;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s INPUT-EVENT-DEVICE IDLE-TIMEOUT\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program reads barcodes from INPUT-EVENT-DEVICE,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "waiting at most IDLE-TIMEOUT seconds for a new barcode.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "The INPUT-EVENT-DEVICE is grabbed, the digits do not appear as\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "inputs in the machine.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "You can at any time end the program by sending it a\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SIGINT (Ctrl+C), SIGHUP, or SIGTERM signal.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (install_done(SIGINT) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) ||
        install_done(SIGTERM)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    {
        double value, check;
        char dummy;
        if (sscanf(argv[2], " %lf %c", &value, &dummy) != 1 || value < 0.001) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid idle timeout value (in seconds).\n", argv[2]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        ms = (unsigned long)(value * 1000.0);
        check = (double)ms / 1000.0;

        if (value < check - 0.001 || value > check + 0.001 || ms < 1UL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Idle timeout is too long.\n", argv[2]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (barcode_open(&dev, argv[1])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open barcode input event device: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1) {
        char    code[BARCODE_MAXLEN + 1];
        size_t  len;

        if (done) {
            status = EINTR;
            break;
        }

        len = barcode_read(&dev, code, sizeof code, ms);
        if (errno) {
            status = errno;
            break;
        }
        if (len < (size_t)1) {
            status = ETIMEDOUT;
            break;
        }

        printf("%zu-digit barcode: %s\n", len, code);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    if (status == EINTR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Signaled to exit. Complying.\n");
        fflush(stderr);
        exitcode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else
    if (status == ETIMEDOUT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Timed out, no more barcodes.\n");
        fflush(stderr);
        exitcode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input event device %s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(status));
        fflush(stderr);
        exitcode = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (barcode_close(&dev)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Error closing input event device %s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        fflush(stderr);
        exitcode = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return exitcode;
}
```

As you can see, it just prints the barcodes to standard output (and any error messages and warnings to standard error). To compile it, I recommend using the following `Makefile` (indentation must be using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, not spaces):

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS := -lrt

.PHONY: all clean

all: clean example

clean:
    rm -f example *.o

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

example: example.o barcode.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o example
```

To compile, create the four files listed above, then run

```
make clean example
```

Running for example

```
./example /dev/input/event4 5.0
```

will read barcodes from `/dev/input/event4`, but will exit at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (INT signal), HUP signal, TERM signal, or if no barcode appears within 5 seconds.

Note that if only a partial barcode is read within that 5 seconds, we do get that partial part (and could just try and read the rest of it), but the above example program ignores the partial, and only shows the timeout.

Questions?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is a reason to use O_NONBLOCK. The read is blocking and when there is no data anymore, my program has to recognise that. And I sleep for 1 second so there are not thousands of calls, there is only one call per second.

Comment: @Andre: You'd be better off not using O_NONBLOCK. If you want a timeout, use a periodic timer with about timeout/2 period. The delivery of the signal will interrupt the blocking read. Do you need real example code?

Comment: I never worked with this stuff, so a example would be interesting :)

Comment: by the way, I solved my problem with a extra-thread. This thread is now reading(and blocking) and gives the results through a pipe to the main-process.

Comment: @Andre: A separate privileged process is a workable solution (as you can run that separate process with different credentials) but you should add an `udev` rule to allow a specific user and/or group to read from the device. I've added my own initial approach -- only very lightly tested -- to this answer.