# Grab a device in C

Tags: c, linux, device

How is it possible to grab a device in C (let's say a mouse?) so that only a given process can use it?

For example it would allow the mouse to be used only on the current process.

I'm creation a virtual device and I write on "/dev/uinput" to send mouse movements. How can I restrict this virtual mouse to only one process.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, (suspect XY problem)?

Comment: @MartinJames I've created a virtual mouse (uinput). I want to try to grab this mouse and make it unusable for other processes while I grab it with one process.

Comment: I'm not a kernel programmer (yet), but in your device `open` call (in the kernel module), you can have a static bool/counter that counts how many times the device has been opened and if it has already been opened (and not closed) just disallow any open requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are [`evtest`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/) or [`evemu`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/) insufficient for your testing needs? They are in standard repositories in most Linux distributions, and certainly suffice for casual testing.

I have posted some example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956584/1475978) as an answer on [how to read barcodes from a specific input event device in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942421/read-barcodes-from-input-event-linux-c). It has timeout support, and grabs the input device (using `ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1)` on the input event device file descriptor), so that the events are not propagated and other processes that try to grab the device fail with `EBUSY`.

It should not be too difficult to modify it to examine the event structures provided by your device in a way you find comfortable.